# Propagating properties from parent pom.xml to grandchild

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a project whose structure goes like this

```
sw
 |-aim-pom.xml
 |-website
      |-pom.xml
      |-package
          |-pom.xml
```

My aim-pom.xml looks like this

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
   <product>aim</product>
</properties>

<modules>
   <module>website/package</module>
</modules>
```

Basically I cant seem to get the value of the property 'product' in website/package/pom.xml where I am doing some conditional logic based on it. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Do a "mvn help:effective-pom" in the "package" module to see if the property is there. If not, make sure that that module specifies aim-pom.xml (or one of its children) as its parent POM. Remember that in Maven, aggregation (modules build sub-modules via the reactor) and inheritance (POMs have other POMs as parents) are [separate concepts](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit).

Comment: That property is not listed. The thing is, I cant change the parent of the pom as there are other build flavors that adhere to a different hierarchy. This will break if I change the parent of package/pom.xml. I am just trying to add another flavor without breaking the existing ones. Can a pom.xml have more than one parent (i.e. multiple inheritance)?

Comment: No, a POM can only have one parent.